# AWS EC2 Alarm that triggers when log in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to create a CloudWatch alarm that triggers when my EC2 instance is accessed from a remote location (using SSH login with key pairs, for example)?

Comment: You'd have to push a custom metric, e.g. remote_login_count into CloudWatch and then create an alarm on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built capability to perform an action when users login to an Amazon EC2 instance. You would have to **write a script** that activates when users login, checks the situation and then triggers a notification.

Amazon CloudWatch alarms trigger when a metric exceeds a pre-determined value. Therefore, you would need to do the following:

- Have your custom script detect the situation and then [publish a custom metric to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html)
- Create an **Alarm** in CloudWatch that triggers when the metric exceeds your desired value (for example, when it is greater than zero)
- Configure your alarm to respond as desired (eg send a notification via SNS)

If you just wish to receive a notification when the user logs-in, you could bypass CloudWatch and just have your script **publish a message to the SNS (Simple Notification Service) topic directly**. It would have the same result.